# Remove appended headers on csv split

Tags: python, csv

When splitting a large csv based on the second column values I am appending to each separate file. However I do not want it to append the Header after the first file.

```
def split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, keyfunc):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    csv_writers = {}
    for row in csv_reader:
        k = keyfunc(row)
        with open(os.path.join(dst_dir, k), mode='a', newline='') as output:
            writer = csv.writer(output)
            writer.writerow(header)
            csv_writers[k] = writer
            csv_writers[k].writerow(row[0:1])
```

This is what I am currently getting:

```
<option value=''>Choose SubGroup</option>
<option value='/2007-Accord-LX-Belts-s/5380.htm'>Belts</option>
<option value=''>Choose SubGroup</option>
<option value='/2007-Accord-LX-Belts-s/5381.htm'>Belts</option>
<option value=''>Choose SubGroup</option>
<option value='/2007-Accord-LX-Cooling-Fan-s/15089.htm'>Cooling Fan</option>
```

Here is what I would like:

```
<option value=''>Choose SubGroup</option>
<option value='/2007-Accord-LX-Belts-s/5380.htm'>Belts</option>
<option value='/2007-Accord-LX-Belts-s/5381.htm'>Belts</option>
<option value='/2007-Accord-LX-Cooling-Fan-s/15089.htm'>Cooling Fan</option>
```

UPDATE:

```
def split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, keyfunc):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    csv_writers ={}
    headers={}
    for row in csv_reader:
        k = keyfunc(row)
        if k in headers:
            with open(os.path.join(dst_dir, k), 'w') as output:
                csv_writers[k].writerow([header])
        else:
            headers[k]=1

        with open(os.path.join(dst_dir, k), mode='a', newline='') as output:
            writer = csv.writer(output)
            csv_writers[k] = writer
            csv_writers[k].writerow(row[0:1])
```

I updated the code and now am receiving a "Key Error" What could I have wrong?

Here is an example of the file to be split:

```
<option value=''>Choose SubGroup</option>, ParentID
<option value='/1990-Accord-DX-Glass-s/37918.htm'>Glass</option>,Accord1990DX422F22A1BodyHardwareBackGlass
<option value='/1990-Accord-DX-Glass-s/37919.htm'>Glass</option>,Accord1990DX422F22A1BodyHardwareBackGlass
<option value='/1990-Accord-DX-Reveal-Moldings-s/69090.htm'>Reveal Moldings</option>,Accord1990DX422F22A1BodyHardwareBackGlass
<option value='/1990-Accord-DX-Reveal-Moldings-s/69091.htm'>Reveal Moldings</option>,Accord1990DX422F22A1BodyHardwareBackGlass
<option value='/1990-Accord-DX-Center-s/10331.htm'>Center</option>,Accord1990DX422F22A1BodyHardwareConsole
<option value='/1990-Accord-DX-Cowl-s/16006.htm'>Cowl</option>,Accord1990DX422F22A1BodyHardwareCowl
<option value='/1990-Accord-DX-Exterior-Trim-s/26889.htm'>Exterior Trim</option>,Accord1990DX422F22A1BodyHardwareFender
<option value='/1990-Accord-DX-Exterior-Trim-s/26890.htm'>Exterior Trim</option>,Accord1990DX422F22A1BodyHardwareFender
```

here is Error:
Key Error: 'Accord1990DX422F22A1BodyHardwareBackGlass.txt'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing how the input file is structured, I suppose the easiest way is to check for the first appearance of `k`.  If it is the first appearance, then you can open up a file, write the header, and that (and any subsequent appearance) can be appended to a header file.  Therefore your code would look like:

```
headers={}
for row in csv_reader:
    k = keyfunc(row)
    if k in headers:
        with open(os.path.join(dst_dir, k), 'w') as output:
            writer.writerow(header)
    else:
        headers[k]=1
    with open(os.path.join(dst_dir, k), mode='a', newline='') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        csv_writers[k] = writer
        csv_writers[k].writerow(row[0:1])
```

By using the `'w'` option to open the file initially, you also don't accidentally append onto an old run, instead creating a new output file.  Otherwise if you run the problem with an issue, the files will forever append - which could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get every second row you might have to consider to use something like :

```
rows[::2]
```

In your specific case, it should be enough:

```
def split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, keyfunc):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    write_header = true
    csv_writers = {}
    for row in csv_reader:
        k = keyfunc(row)
        with open(os.path.join(dst_dir, k), mode='a', newline='') as output:
            writer = csv.writer(output)

            while write_header:
                writer.writerow(header)
                write_header = false

            csv_writers[k] = writer
            csv_writers[k].writerow(row[0:1])
```